# Screenshot to post twitter sheet

Tags: ios, twitter

I am working on my application to add twitter feature to share the screenshot of my current viewcontroller. Is there any in built method that I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1778282/751268) answer has the following method to create a screenshot:

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

It returns a UIImage, which you can then use like this:

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
tweetSheet.image = [self captureView:self.view]; // or self.navigationController.view
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: @Scoot, could please also look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485895/resizing-uiimage-to-post-to-twitter-sheet-ios